# Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns and sum

Tags: mysql

Can MySQL convert columns into rows, dynamically adding as many columns as are needed for the rows. I have tried other solutions but they dont seem to solve my unique case.
This is the table with the data

Table A

```
    +---------+-------------+------+
    |driver_id|stage_name   |points|
    +---------+-------------+------+
    |1        |Stage 1 50cc |20    |
    +---------+-------------+------+
    |1        |Stage 2 50cc |17    |
    +---------+-------------+------+
    |2        |Stage 1 50cc |17    |
    +---------+-------------+------+
    |2        |Stage 2 50cc |15    |
    +---------+-------------+------+
    |3        |Stage 1 75cc |17    |
    +---------+-------------+------+
    |3        |Stage 2 75cc |15    |
    +---------+-------------+------+
    |4        |Stage 1 75cc |15    |
    +---------+-------------+------+
    |4        |Stage 2 75cc |20    |
    +---------+-------------+------+
```

I would like query that formats it as follows

```
    +---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
    |driver_id|Stage 1 50cc |Stage 2 50cc |Stage 1 75cc |Stage 2 75cc | Total Points |
    +---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
    |1        |     20      |     17      |    null     |    null     |    37        |
    +---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
    |2        |     17      |     15      |    null     |    null     |    32        |
    +---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
    |3        |     null    |     null    |     16      |     15      |    31        |
    +---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
    |4        |     null    |     null    |     15      |    20       |    35        |
    +---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

As you can see the last col has a calculation based on the total of the various stages across for that driver.
The sum isnt very important right now but having the scores first but if all is possible then splendid.

Comment: Well, I don't think so. But MySQL has a JSON column type that could be interesting. Look into it.

Comment: Normalise your schema, and handle issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the data this way (or possibly a step further in normalisation):

```
+-----------+----------+----+--------+
| driver_id | stage_no | cc | points |
+-----------+----------+----+--------+
|         1 |        1 | 50 |     20 |
|         1 |        2 | 50 |     17 |
|         2 |        1 | 50 |     17 |
|         2 |        2 | 50 |     15 |
|         3 |        1 | 75 |     17 |
|         3 |        2 | 75 |     15 |
|         4 |        1 | 75 |     15 |
|         4 |        2 | 75 |     20 |
+-----------+----------+----+--------+
```

Then I would use this query:

```
SELECT driver_id, stage_no, cc, points FROM my_table ORDER BY driver_id,stage,cc;
```

Then everything else I would handle in application code.